# Flask Forms + Blueprints: KeyError: 'A secret key is required to use CSRF'

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to import my Flask app into a daemon. I imported most of my code into `routes.py` and adapted it to the blueprint. When I run the daemon, I get `KeyError: 'A secret key is required to use CSRF'`. If I change to `MyForm(csrf_enabled=False)`then it works fine. Why isn't `app.config['SECRET_KEY']` working?

`routes.py`

```
import re, csv, os, logging
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, Blueprint
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
from pxeadmin.daemon.implementation import PxeAdmin


LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Make sure this matches your repo's template directory
TEMPLATE_FOLDER = 'templates'
DAEMON_BLUEPRINT = Blueprint('daemon.routes.blueprint', __name__, template_folder=TEMPLATE_FOLDER)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "xc7rx86xafxf0ex8cxd2xb6flxfel4stLxd5xdbx18Sx1e"
app.register_blueprint(DAEMON_BLUEPRINT)


class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    """Index page form class"""
    name = StringField('Full Name:')
    uname = StringField('Username:')
    asset = StringField('Asset Tag:')
    mac = StringField('MAC Address:')
    mac_remove = StringField('MAC Address:')


@DAEMON_BLUEPRINT.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    """main page/form for adding/viewing/removing entries from sys_map.csv"""
    pxe_form = MyForm()
    mac_remove_i = pxe_form.data['mac_remove']
    name_i = pxe_form.data['name']
    uname_i = pxe_form.data['uname']
    asset_i = pxe_form.data['asset']
    mac_i = pxe_form.data['mac']
    if pxe_form.validate_on_submit() and pxe_form.data['mac_remove']:
        remove_one(mac_remove_i)
    elif pxe_form.validate_on_submit() and name_i and uname_i and \
        asset_i and mac_i:
        add_to_list(name_i, uname_i, asset_i, mac_i)

    content = the_list()
    return render_template('index.html', form=pxe_form, contents=content)
```

`__main__.py`

```
from pxeadmin.daemon.implementation import PxeAdmin
from pxeadmin.daemon.routes import DAEMON_BLUEPRINT, register_error_handlers


def _main():
    # Instantiate the singleton. We must do this first to get an instance of the Flask app.
    daemon_app = PxeAdmin()

    # Set up the Flask error handlers and registering the daemon blueprint so that our HTTP endpoints work.
    register_error_handlers(daemon_app.flask_app)
    daemon_app.flask_app.register_blueprint(DAEMON_BLUEPRINT)

    # Run the implementation.
    daemon_app.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _main()
```

`implementation.py`

```
from cmdlineutil.daemon import Daemon
from cmdlineutil.property_manager import PropertyManager, Property
from pxeadmin.daemon.dependencies import build_dependencies

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class PxeAdmin(Daemon):
    """Entry point for python daemon applications.
    name = 'pxe-admin-app'

    def __init__(self):
        super(PxeAdmin, self).__init__(PxeAdmin.name)
```

I also properly included the form hidden tag.

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  {{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name(size=20) }} <br>
  .....
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created an `app` in `routes.py`, but it appears to have no relation to the `daemon_app.flask_app` instance you're serving. Any config you did to your `Flask` instance doesn't apply to a separate `Flask` instance. Apply the config to `daemon_app.flask_app.config`.